# How long does a ClientLogin for Google Data API stay valid/usable?

Tags: web-services, authentication, google-data-api

On this [google documentation page](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin.html#RecallAuthToken) I found out that you can reuse previously retrieved tokens. Now, I'm currently having trouble (unpredictable results) with retrieving a key in the first place, so whenever I have one, I would like to be able to reuse it. For how long can this be reused?